Need to pass an external variable into a tidy pipe, but feature is deprecated
I am having difficulty getting around this issue of needing to pass a df and colname to a function. Calling that assigned colname variable within a tidy pipe calls the error https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html but the use of all_of() does not work in this instance.
Context: I am passing singular excel sheets to the function and each sheet has a different title for the first column. So I need to pass the column name as an external variable to the function, then within the function to a tidy pipe to pivot.
Pass a data.frame column name to a function The link here discusses the first issue, passing column name to function and I am using the deparse(substitute) method. But the problem is arising as part of tidyverse I'm pretty sure. I just can't see a way around this?
    totals <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Units,    ~NACE,  ~"1990", ~"1991", ~"1992", ~"1993", ~"1994", ~"1995", ~"1996", ~"1997", ~"1998",
  "Imports",    0,     4155,   5145,    7355,    6155,    4715,    4155,    4155,    4155,    4155,
  "Exports",    0,     3952,   3952,    3952,    3952,    3952,    3952,    3952,    3952,    3952,
  "X",         14,    99598,  99598,   99598,   99598,   99598,   99598,   99598,   99598,   99598,
  "Y",         16,     6260,   6260,    6260,    6260,    6260,    6260,    6260,    6260,    6260,
  "Z",          8,    36583,  36583,   36583,   36583,   36583,   36583,   36583,   36583,   36583,
)

    # ---- reshape data ----
    reshape_data <- function(data, colname){

      main <- totals %>%
          select(!NACE)
  
      new_col <- main %>% 
        pivot_longer(!{{colname}}, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Total Supply") %>% 
        rename(`Total.Units` = {{colname}}) 
}
 
    
    data <- (totals, "Units") # or colname = "Units", neither work

Error in pivot_longer():
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column "Units" doesn't exist.
Any ideas how to approach this task?

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show how you are calling the reshape_data function. What exactly is the error you are getting?

It's hard to answer without testable data, but can't you just use the column index on pivot_longer, e.g. pivot_longer(-1)?

I can't reproduce an error given the gist of your code here. If data <- mtcars; colname = c("cyl", "gear"), I can do data  |> select(!am)  |> slice(3) |> pivot_longer(!colname) |> slice(rep(1:n(), each=5)) with no error at all. I second MrFlick's request to make this reproducible. I also don't understand "column name cannot be seen"; I think demonstrating with sample data you provide, show you calling this function, and the results (messages, warnings, errors, and all).

This should also be doable using the curly-curly syntax: myfun <- function(data, colname) { data %>% pivot_longer({{colname}}) %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 5))};  myfun(mtcars, colnames(mtcars[10]))

@Jon Spring: tried that above as suggested but doesn't seem to work, had also tried using [[ ]] similarly to pass string literal as suggested in one of the links I added but that also didn't seem to work. But your suggestion works within the function elsewhere, just not within pivot_longer. Thank you!

@ZéLoff - that worked! I didn't know about this option, clear and simple. It's going to be very useful. Not sure why this way works and not the others

Using tidyverse 2.0.0, this works for me on your data: `reshape_data <- function(data, colname){
data %>%
select(!NACE) %>%
pivot_longer( !{{colname}}, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Total Supply") %>%
rename('Total.Units' = {{colname}})
};
reshape_data(totals, Units)`

As suggested by Zé Loff in comments above, using pivot_longer(-1) worked.
Suggestion by Jon Spring to wrap colname in {{}} also works;
reshape_data <- function(data, colname){data %>%      
       select(!NACE) %>%     
       pivot_longer(!{{colname}}, names_to = "Year",
       values_to = "Total Supply") %>%     
       rename('Total.Units' = {{colname}}) };  

reshape_data(totals, Units)

